# UnicodeWarning when comparing unicode strings to unicode results from os.walk command

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, python-2.7, os.walk

Using python 2.7 I'm doing an os.walk with these files http://www.2shared.com/file/biSx7NI-/comer.html and then comparing the result against an array. In the actual program this array won't be predefined. The code that I am trying to use is as follows

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os.path
group = ['comer.txt', 'coma.txt', 'comamos.txt', 'coman.txt', 'comas.txt', 'come.txt', 'comed.txt', 'comemos.txt', 'comen.txt', 'comeremos.txt', 'comer\xc3\xa1.txt', 'comer\xc3\xa1n.txt', 'comer\xc3\xa1s.txt', 'comer\xc3\xa9.txt', 'comer\xc3\xa9is.txt', 'comer\xc3\xada.txt', 'comer\xc3\xadais.txt', 'comer\xc3\xadamos.txt', 'comer\xc3\xadan.txt', 'comer\xc3\xadas.txt', 'comes.txt', 'comido.txt', 'comiendo.txt', 'comiera.txt', 'comierais.txt', 'comieran.txt', 'comieras.txt', 'comiere.txt', 'comiereis.txt', 'comieren.txt', 'comieres.txt', 'comieron.txt', 'comimos.txt', 'comiste.txt', 'comisteis.txt', 'comi\xc3\xa9ramos.txt', 'comi\xc3\xa9remos.txt', 'comi\xc3\xb3.txt', 'como.txt', 'com\xc3\xa1is.txt', 'com\xc3\xa9is.txt', 'com\xc3\xad.txt', 'com\xc3\xada.txt', 'com\xc3\xadais.txt', 'com\xc3\xadamos.txt', 'com\xc3\xadan.txt', 'com\xc3\xadas.txt', 'comer\xc3\xa1.txt', 'comer\xc3\xa9.txt', 'comer\xc3\xada.txt', 'comer\xc3\xadais.txt']

print "********what we have*********"
i=0
for f in group:
    group[i] = os.path.basename(f)
    group[i] = unicode(group[i], "utf-8")        
    print group[i]
    i += 1

wantedResults = []
print "********what we want*********"
for(path, dirs, files) in os.walk("C:\corpus\zz-auto generated\spanish\comer"):
    wantedResults.append(files)
for f in wantedResults[0]:
    print f

print "********problems*********"
for resultWanted in wantedResults[0]:
    if resultWanted not in group:
        print "did not match our wanted results: " + resultWanted
for result in group:
    if result not in wantedResults[0]:
        print "extra file: " + result
```

I'm getting this error:

> Warning (from warnings module):
>    File "C:\Users***\Desktop\osWalkTest.py", line 26
>      if result not in wantedResults[0]:
>   UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - >interpreting them as being unequal

I could really use some help in getting the predefined array and the array from the os.walk to properly compare. I've looked this up on Google, and have tried many combinations of encoding and decoding the two arrays, but nothing seems to work. Thanks.

Comment: When using `# coding: utf-8` you can use `group = [u'comerán.txt',...]` instead of hand-coding utf-8 byte strings like `['comer\xc3\xa1n.txt',...]` and calling `unicode` on them.  Make sure to actually save the file in UTF-8 encoding, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried (note the 'u' before the string, which turns it to Unicode):

`for(path, dirs, files) in os.walk(u"C:/corpus/zz-auto generated/spanish/comer"):`

(note that having back-slashes in a string is not a good idea, Unicode or not).

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much, I have been looking forever for an answer to this problem.